# Flink rocksdb doesn't seems to write to localdir

Tags: apache-flink, rocksdb

I have a flink environment with the following configurations.

```yaml
state.backend: rocksdb
state.backend.async: true
state.backend.fs.memory-threshold: 1024
state.backend.fs.write-buffer-size: 4096
state.backend.incremental: true
state.backend.local-recovery: false
state.checkpoints.num-retained: 1
state.backend.rocksdb.localdir: /flink_data/rocksdb
state.backend.rocksdb.memory.managed: true
```

> flink_data - PVC we claim in openshift pod

We are a job we large state and windows of cuple of hours, from what I understand rocksdb is better suited for large state jobs because of its ability to flush some of the data from the memory to lical storge as opposed to the default state backend that work only on the memory.

From the configuration we set we expect that the job that use rocksdb will flush the data to local dir.
From the check we did on the pvc of the pod I saw the rocks db file size are only  280kb.

In the other hand the taskmanger have 19Gb total process memory that from that he use 11.7Gb to the flink managed memory(that from the metrics in the flink ui seems to be always in 100% usage)
In addition to that we see from the rocksdb metrics that there is lots of keys in the db

> All the files that have been craeted are exactly 4kb each

Tnx for the help in advance

Comment: The configuration appears correct. Are you sure it is being applied?

Comment: In the ui it's says that the applied state backend is indeed rocksdb. And I see in the localdir that it indeed create somefile but there size is no more the few kb. I saw in addtion to that all the files that were there are exactly 4kb each.